# How do I get a row of json using jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

I have json that is being returned from a source

```
[{"Title":"Gross Wages","Last":"$40,000","MTD":"$40,000","QTD":"$40,000","YTD":"$40,000"},
{"Title":"Total Taxes","Last":"$50,000","MTD":"$50,000","QTD":"$50,000","YTD":"$50,000"},
{"Title":"Total Benefits","Last":"$60,000","MTD":"$60,000","QTD":"$60,000","YTD":"$60,000"},
{"Title":"Regular Hours","Last":"$450","MTD":"$450","QTD":"$450","YTD":"$450"},
{"Title":"OT Hours","Last":"57.5","MTD":"57.5","QTD":"57.5","YTD":"57.5"},
 {"Title":"New Hires","Last":"6","MTD":"6","QTD":"6","YTD":"6"},
{"Title":"Terminations","Last":"1","MTD":"1","QTD":"1","YTD":"1"}]
```

I want to be able to use the first row only of the json.  I can load all the rows into my table like this.

```
$.getJSON(execOverview, function (json) {
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

                $.each(json[i], function (key, value) {
                    //Populate table row content
                        $('#execTbl tbody').append("<td>" + value + "</td>");
                });
                //Wrap elements
                $('#execTbl > tbody > td').wrapAll("<tr></tr>");
            }
        });
```

I am just unsure how to load only the first row into the table

Comment: You can target a specific index like this: First row: `json[0].Title`,  Second row: `json[1].Title`

Comment: Thanks jack.  How do I write it so only json[0] loads in the table?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Since you are looking for only the first row ( at index 0 ) , you don't need `for` block. Just check for the length greater than zero.

```
if(json.length > 0)
{
   $.each(json[0], function (key, value) {
    //Populate table row content
   $('#execTbl tbody').append("<td>" + value + "</td>");
   });
   //Wrap elements  
$('#execTbl > tbody > td').wrapAll("<tr></tr>");
}
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/6d5ry9br/3/